# Set different color for NSLinkAttributeName

Tags: ios, hyperlink, nsattributedstring

I know that the `UITextView.linkTextAttributes` can change the color of all the `NSLinkAttributeName` link in the `UITextView`. But i want to set different color for each link. I don't know how to do it. Please tell me if you know. Thanks.

Comment: you can find the range of each link and set explicit attributes for each